# Getting error in compiling Unity UWP build with Visual Studio 2017.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, visual-studio-2017, build-error

I am porting Unity game to Universal Windows Platform. But during creating build in Visual Studio 2017.3, I got this error:

> The command ""F:\Games 4\Police Sniffer Dog ChaseV1.0\WinStore_10\Unity\Tools\AssemblyConverter.exe" -platform=uap -lock="F:\Games 4\Police Sniffer Dog ChaseV1.0\WinStore_10\Police Sniffer Dog Chase\project.lock.json" -bits=64 -configuration=Debug -removeDebuggableAttribute=False -path="." -path="..\Players\UAP\x64\Debug" "F:\Games 4\Police Sniffer Dog ChaseV1.0\WinStore_10\Police Sniffer Dog Chase\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll" "F:\Games 4\Police Sniffer Dog ChaseV1.0\WinStore_10\Police Sniffer Dog Chase\Assembly-CSharp.dll" "F:\Games 4\Police Sniffer Dog ChaseV1.0\WinStore_10\Police Sniffer Dog Chase\Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll" "F:\Games 4\Police Sniffer Dog ChaseV1.0\WinStore_10\Police Sniffer Dog Chase\Assembly-UnityScript.dll" "F:\Games 4\Police Sniffer Dog ChaseV1.0\WinStore_10\Police Sniffer Dog Chase\UnityEngine.dll" "F:\Games 4\Police Sniffer Dog ChaseV1.0\WinStore_10\Police Sniffer Dog Chase\UnityEngine.UI.dll" "F:\Games 4\Police Sniffer Dog ChaseV1.0\WinStore_10\Police Sniffer Dog Chase\UnityEngine.Networking.dll" "F:\Games 4\Police Sniffer Dog ChaseV1.0\WinStore_10\Police Sniffer Dog Chase\LightMixerScripts.dll"" exited with code 1. Police Sniffer Dog Chase    F:\Games 4\Police Sniffer Dog ChaseV1.0\WinStore_10\Police Sniffer Dog Chase\Police Sniffer Dog Chase.csproj    279

[image]

I remove all errors in Unity now. Everything is working fine in Unity but Visual Studio generate this error during compilation. Its happened with all games I try to compile with Visual Studio.

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with Nuget. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465376/build-error-this-project-references-nuget)

Comment: What's the VS version you are using? Is it 2017.3?

Comment: Yes using 2017.3

Comment: Maybe you need W10 SO. I had similar problem with Xamarin Studio

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, it seems you are having the same issue here: [.NET scripting backend and Visual Studio 2017.3 incompatibility](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/net-scripting-backend-and-visual-studio-2017-3-incompatibility.487833/).

There is a compatibility issue between Unity and Visual Studio 2017 update 3 when targeting UWP, using .NET scripting backend (IL2CPP scripting backend is not affected) and building generated Visual Studio project.

To fix this issue, you can try with IL2CPP scripting backend, or upgrade Unity to the following version:

- 5.5 version with the fix: [**5.5.4p5**](https://beta.unity3d.com/download/7a1d1547db9c/UnityDownloadAssistant-5.5.4p5.exe)
- 5.6 version with the fix: [**5.6.3p2**](https://beta.unity3d.com/download/b3d7a6428558/UnityDownloadAssistant-5.6.3p2.exe)
- 2017.1 version with fix: [**2017.1.0p5**](http://beta.unity3d.com/download/de463fc61bac/UnityDownloadAssistant-2017.1.0p5.exe)
- 2017.2 version with fix: [**2017.2.0b7**](http://beta.unity3d.com/download/4bc201a72e4a/UnityDownloadAssistant-2017.2.0b7.exe)